# RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file failed: Permission denied

Tags: python, rasterio

I am tring to resample Chirps data from 0.25 to 0.0025degrees resolution with the following code, I am still using 1 as an upscale factor to get the code to run:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
import os

upscale_factor = 1

i = 0
for files in os.listdir(r'D:/CHIRPS RSDATA/CHIRPS(1981-1983)'):
    if files [-4:] == '.tif':
        i = i + 1
 
        fp = r'D:\CHIRPS RSDATA\CHIRPS(1981-1983)'+'\\'+files
        print(fp)
        dataset = rasterio.open(fp)
        
        data = dataset.read(out_shape=(dataset.count,
                           int(dataset.height*upscale_factor),
                           int(dataset.width*upscale_factor)),
                            resampling=Resampling.bilinear) #You can change the resamplng technique here
        
        if data.shape[-1] != 0 and data.shape[-2] != 0:
                
            transform=dataset.transform*dataset.transform.scale((dataset.width/data.shape[-1]),(dataset.height/data.shape[-2]))
            
            height = int(dataset.height*upscale_factor)
            width = int(dataset.width*upscale_factor)
            
            with rasterio.Env():
                profile = dataset.profile
                profile.update(transform=transform,driver='GTiff',height=height,width=width)
                
                with rasterio.open('D:\CHIRPS RSDATA\CHIRPS(1981-1983)\Rainfalls',"w",**profile) as output: 
                    output.write(data)
                    print("Image resampled...")
```

and I am getting this error:

```
runfile('D:/CHIRPS RSDATA/CHIRPS(1981-1983)/Resampling_python.py', wdir='D:/CHIRPS RSDATA/CHIRPS(1981-1983)')
D:\CHIRPS RSDATA\CHIRPS(1981-1983)\chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 1139, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__

  File "rasterio\_err.pyx", line 215, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_pointer

CPLE_OpenFailedError: Attempt to create new tiff file 'D:/CHIRPS RSDATA/CHIRPS(1981-1983)/Rainfalls' failed: Permission denied


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\CHIRPS RSDATA\CHIRPS(1981-1983)\Resampling_python.py", line 42, in <module>
    with rasterio.open('D:\CHIRPS RSDATA\CHIRPS(1981-1983)\Rainfalls',"w",**profile) as output:

  File "C:\Users\khoda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py", line 435, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\khoda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 225, in open
    s = writer(path, mode, driver=driver,

  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 1143, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__

RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file 'D:/CHIRPS RSDATA/CHIRPS(1981-1983)/Rainfalls' failed: Permission denied
```

I tried changing the permissions of the folder with no luck, I also double checked the synaxes as other people have suggested. Please help.

Comment: See https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/2058 ?

Comment: Could you please include your code and the complete error trace? In any case, what is the specified TIFF path? Have you verified that you have write permission at that path?